# Using C# how do you determine if an excel file located on server has been updated. This check needs to be performed every 24 hrs

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, windows-services

So far I have tried this code which shows for 1 file last update.

```
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Desktop\test.xlsx");
        DateTime lastWriteTime = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
        Console.WriteLine(lastWriteTime);
        MessageBox.Show("test" + lastWriteTime);
```

I want to know how this could be automatically ran every 24 hrs as I need to perform a check on various files of more than 1 folder based on the file system.

How to make it a windows service which runs in background.

Comment: Why not just make a scheduled task for an executable since you only need it to run every 24 hours, and avoid a Windows Service all together?

Comment: I would lik to know how to make a scheduled task...any more light on it...since I am new to it.

Comment: That's baked into Windows. No code required. Windows can make a task to run a program on a schedule you choose. You can read more about it [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task).

Comment: AFAIK, scheduled tasks only run if the computer is logged in - so if you've got a server that boots up and stops at the logon prompt, scheduled tasks don't run but windows services which are configured to start at start up will run.

Comment: Scheduled tasks work fine if no user is logged in as long as you don't show a UI. Coincidentally, this is the same limitation that Windows Services have: you can't show a UI.

Comment: @andrew It's very easy to create a Scheduled Task that runs if no one is logged in. http://imgur.com/g75qJ

Comment: THanks; i've learned something new.

Answer (score 3):

One potential solution here is to create a Windows service as mentioned.  [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/getting-started/) is an open source project that can help you quickly create Windows services that are easy to install and uninstall.  The documentation is a little sparse but it's relatively easy to use the example to get up and running.  Tangentially, I'd also like to give you some advice about the FileSystemWatcher that I've learned through experience: You'll want to "watch" for a minute or two at a time, or some interval that's reasonable, then recreate the watcher again.  If the underlying file system falls out from under the FileSystemWatcher, it won't know.  This can make it seem like the FileSystemWatcher "doesn't work".

Comment: thanks for TopShelf link, looks like it will suit what the op needs!